# Can a while loop evaluate to a value?

Tags: loops, rust

I'm learning Rust and today I stumbled upon being able to assign variables through `if`/`else` expressions. For instance:

```
let y = 5;

let x = if y > 20 { 20 } else { y };
```

Is there some way to do this with a `while` loop? I tried:

```
fn main() {
    let mut n = 0;

    let mut num = 0;

    num += while n < 10 {
        n += 1;
        5
    };
}
```

with the hope that `num` would eventually be equal to 50, with the while loop incrementing `num` by five each iteration, but I get the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:8:9
  |
8 |         5
  |         ^ expected (), found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `()`
             found type `{integer}`

error[E0277]: cannot add-assign `()` to `{integer}`
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     num += while n < 10 {
  |         ^^ no implementation for `{integer} += ()`
  |
  = help: the trait `std::ops::AddAssign<()>` is not implemented for `{integer}`
```

Naturally, I could put the `num += 5` inside the while loop, but that takes the fun out of it.

This is my first day with Rust, so I don't even know if it's possible to do what I have in mind. Is this indeed possible? Am I making a syntax error?

This is another version of the code I'm trying to run, but also fails to work:

```
fn main() {
    let mut num = 0;

    num += while num < 50 {
        5
    };
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. The value of a `while` loop is always `()`, the unit type.

[RFC 1624](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1624-loop-break-value.md) did enhance `loop` loops to be able to break with a value:

```
let x = loop {
    break 42;
};
println!("{}", x);
```

Comment: That RFC is for something quite different from what was attempted here; I can confidently say that the summation of each iteration to yield the loop expression's result is never going to happen.

Comment: Note that this was released in [Rust 1.19 (2017-07-20)](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/07/20/Rust-1.19.html)